# ECE graduate with IT exp can eligible for australia PR

Tags: australia

I am graduated from Electronics and communication engineering but I am having 4 years of experience in IT company. So am I eligible for applying Australian PR?

Answer (score 1):

You ECE degree will be assessed as ICT minor by ACS, given you had some basic CS courses in your degree like Data Structures, Intro to programming, etc. For ICT minor degrees to be assessed positive, you need minimum five years of experience. But remember, ACS will deduct these 5 years of experience for your positive assessment. So eventually, you will be 0 years. You will have to wait for 3 more years to get 5 points of experience.
You can further contact ACS for clarification. You can also refer to [this official document.](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Summary%20of%20Criteria%20-%202017.pdf)